# Postgres: Calculating the number of working months in the last X years

Tags: postgresql

I users table and a jobs. User has many jobs and jobs have a start_date and end_date:

```
     Column     |            Type             |                     Modifiers                     
----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('jobs_id_seq'::regclass)
 title          | character varying           | 
 employer       | character varying           | 
 start_date     | date                        | 
 end_date       | date                        | 
 user_id        | integer                     |
```

I need to calculate the total number of months that a person has spent working within the past X years.

I've looked at `OVERLAPS` and played with intervals a bit but I can't quite figure out what I need. I want to make sure that even it the start_date is outside the X years range that I still count the months that are inside the range.

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
select sum(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM months) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM months))
 as working_months
from (
select CASE current
 WHEN true THEN
 age(current_date, start_date)
 ELSE age(end_date, start_date) 
END as months
 from jobs inner join users on jobs.user_id = users.id
 where users.id = 4
) as employment_time;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with jobs (start_date, end_date, user_id) as ( values
    ('2000-01-01'::date, '2005-12-31'::date, 1),
    ('2007-10-01', '2008-09-30', 1),
    ('2010-09-01', '2014-10-20', 1)
)
select
    user_id,
    extract(year from work_time) * 12 + extract(month from work_time) as months
from (
    select
        user_id,
        sum(age(upper(period), lower(period))) as work_time
    from (
        select
            user_id,
            daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') *
            daterange((current_date - interval '10 years')::date, current_date)
            as period
        from jobs
    ) s
    group by user_id
) s
;
 user_id | months 
---------+--------
       1 |     70
```

[Range type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) - 
[Range functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

Answer (score 0):

The basic query would be this:

```
SELECT sum(extract(year from months) * 12 + extract(month from months)) AS working_months
FROM (
  SELECT
    age(CASE (start_date, start_date) OVERLAPS (current_date, interval '-5 years')
        WHEN true THEN start_date
        ELSE current_date - interval '5 years'
        END AS strt::timestamp,
        CASE current
        WHEN true THEN current_date
        ELSE end_date
        END AS fin::timestamp) AS months
  FROM jobs
  WHERE user_id = 4) AS employment_time;
```

You may also put this in a SQL function with parameters for the number of years and `user_id`. Note that you throw away partial months from individual jobs. You can add `extract(day from months) / 30` to the top `SELECT` to harvest those partial months into full months.

This assumes that jobs cannot overlap. If they do, then the query becomes much more complex.

Comment: For some reason Postgres is unhappy with the brackets in `interval('-X years')` but when I remove them it barfs on `END AS start::timestamp`.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson: My bad. "Start" is a SQL reserved word and the interval doesn't need the brackets. Answer updated.